# Unique hash/index for time interval

Tags: mongodb, database-design, hash, database

I am working on a simple resource booking app. The use of the resource is exclusive so it can't be booked more than once at the same time. I am wondering if this constraint can be enforced by a unique index instead of having to build validation in code.

The resource can only be booked by block of 30 minutes and the start and end time must be on the hour OR the half hour. So the booking can modeled as an array of blocks that are unique (dividing the timestamp in chunks of 30 minutes).

Can anyone think of a way to hash that so any booking with one or more 30-min. block in common would violate the unique index condition?

NB: I am using MongoDB (I don't think it really matters)

Comment: Maybe a two-dimensional array where your first dimension is a sequence of days (from the epoch of your app) and the second dimension is half hour blocks? I'm not sure what the life of your app will be or if there are only certain hours that the resource might be used, which would reduce the space required significantly. You could also splice out old data at some interval as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if this constraint can be enforced by a unique index instead of having to build validation in code.

Use an unique compound index on the resource id, day and chunk of 30 minutes. Then insert one document for each 30 minutes of period of reservation.

For example, to reserve the resource id 123 on 9 of June 2015 from 8:00 to 9:30 (16<sup>th</sup>, 17<sup>th</sup> and 18<sup>th</sup> 30 minutes period of the day), you insert *3* documents:

```
> db.booking.createIndex({resource: 1,
                          day: 1, period:1},{unique:true})
```

```
{
  resource: 123,
  day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
  period: 16
},
{
  resource: 123,
  day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
  period: 17
},
{
  resource: 123,
  day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
  period: 18
},
```

---

Depending the number en entries, you might consider using embedded documents instead:

```
> db.resource.createIndex({_id: 1,
                           "booking.day": 1,
                           "booking:period":1},{unique:true})
```

And describe your resources like this:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  someOtherResourceAttributes: "...",
  booking: [
    {
      day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
      period: 16
    },
    {
      day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
      period: 17
    },
    {
      day: ISODate("2015-09-06"),
      period: 18
    },
  ]
},
```

This has the great advantage that insert/update would be atomic for the whole reservation. But beware that document size is limited to 16M.

Comment: Thanks! To limit the size of a document I could create a bookings collection, and include nested blocks in "booking" documents. However, I read in the docs that having documents of varying sizes could be an issues. A booking could have 1 to 48 blocks (24hr). What do you think?

Comment: @NathanZ Knowing that you _can_ do it do not mean that you _should_ do it. There are many variations around that idea: for example, depending your use case, you might want to add a `reserved` boolean field, and pre-populate your collection with all periods having `reserved: false` -- and then only update it to `true` when needed. This would solve your "varying sizes documents" concern.